# Does Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR3 compatible with Spring Boot 2.3.11?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I would like to know **Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR3** is compatible with **Spring Boot 2.3.11** ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Spring Cloud project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud) contains a version compatibility table. Spring Cloud Hoxton is compatible with Spring Boot 2.2.x and, as of SR5, Spring Boot 2.3.x. In short, Spring Cloud Hoxton.SR3 is not compatible with Spring Boot 2.3.11.